# Get a list of managed Entity instances in a persistence context

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-4.x

Is there a way to obtain a list of "known" Entity instances for a given Session/EntityManager in JPA/Hibernate 4.x?

By "known" I mean either loaded, created or changed, i.e. a managed entity that exists in a persistence context. I know of `EntityManager#contains` method so I'm guessing that such a list *is* maintained, but how can I get to it?

EDIT:
Also, how can I query the state of the persistent entity (check if it is created, updated, deleted or clean in this persistence context)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

JPA does not define such a capability.  But you can do it using Hibernate calls:

```
final org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor session = em.unwrap( org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor.class );
final org.hibernate.engine.spi.PersistenceContext pc = session.getPersistenceContext();
final Map.Entry<Object,org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityEntry>[] entityEntries = pc.reentrantSafeEntityEntries();
```

`entityEntries` here is an array of Map.Entry instances whose "key" is the entity itself and whose value is an instance of `org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityEntry` that describes various info about the entity, including information like EntityEntry.getStatus().

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Btw, do you happen to know what Status.GONE means in hibernate (EntityEntry.getStatus()) ?

Comment: Status.DELETED indicates that the entity is deleted in regards to the Session/EntityManager.  Status.GONE indicates the row has been deleted from the database.